# Using Scanner class to assign each String in a line to different variables

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm fairly new to java and I'm a little stuck with how I can extract each string in a line from a file and then setting those in values in 6 different variables using Scanner. This is what I have so far:

```
File fileName = new File("studentInfo.txt");
Scanner file = new Scanner(fileName);
while(file.hasNext()){
    String s = file.next();
    System.out.println(s);
}
file.close();
```

studentInfo.txt

```
John Smith 1990 12 25 Junior
Jesse Jane 1993 10 22 Freshman
Jack Ripper 1989 01 14 Senior
```

My output, prints:

```
John
Smith
1990
12
25
Junior
```

So basically I need to set John to firstName, Smith to lastName, 1990 to year, 12 to month, 25 to day, and Junior to classYear, and then loop through the next line and so on. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not consider creating a Person object with all these 6 properties and then setting those properties in your loop? I'm assuming somewhere further down the line you would need access to these values again. It'd be difficult to just assume n number of strings if you don't know how many lines you will have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one scanner for the lines and one for reading each line:

```
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(fileName);
while(file.hasNextLine()){
    String line = lineScanner.nextLine();
    // parse the line
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
    String firstName = sc.next();
    String lastName = sc.next();
    int year = sc.nextInt();
    int month = sc.nextInt();
    int day = sc.nextInt();
    String classYear = sc.next();
    sc.close();
    // use the variables
    // ...
}
file.close();
```